# Stop Calendar from changing time-zone

Tags: google-calendar, lg-g5

I use Google Calendar instead of the stock calendar on my LG G5. I travel internationally on a weekly basis, and the Calendar app would automatically adjust the calendar events' scheduled time once I landed to a different time zone (if Auto Date & Time is on) or once I adjusted the time zone manually (if Auto Date & Time is off).

The fact that Calendar Events' times got changed is utterly impractical and annoying.

For example, I would add an event at 8pm on a future date in that destination of a different time zone, and once I land there, the Calendar event time will be changed to 2pm. This throws off the timing of all my events. I almost missed several flights because the alarm did not go off at the right time, especially in connected flights crossing multiple time zones.

How can I stop Calendar from doing that? If I recall, iPhone does not do that.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of inconvenience of how Google Calendar uses time zones.

Here is a brief explanation of how it uses time zones:

> How Calendar uses time zones
>
> When you create an event, you'll see it in your local time zone. It
> will also show up in the local time zones for anyone you invite, even
> if they're in a different time zone.

Some workarounds:

**1. Disable device time zone**

When you travel to a different time zone, you can see your calendar in the local time.

1. Open the Google Calendar app .
2. In the top left, tap Menu .
3. At the bottom, tap Settings .
4. Tap General.
5. Tap Use device time zone on or off.

> If "Use device time zone" is on, your time zone will update
> automatically as you travel. If "Use device time zone is off", you can
> select a time zone from the drop-down menu.

**2. Create an event in a different time zone**

There is another workaround involving setting time zone for an individual event in Google Calendar.

For example, if you're going on a trip to Bahamas and want to make sure your 2 PM island tour shows up on your calendar correctly, you should choose the time zone for Bahamas while creating your event. i.e

> Create an event
>
> - Open the Calendar app .
> - Tap Create .
> - Tap Event .
> - Start typing in a title for your event. You'll often see suggestions – choose one or keep typing.
> - Tap Done .
> - Edit event details like the date, location, **time**, event visibility, and who's invited. If you don't share your calendar, you
>   won't see visibility settings at all for your event.
> - Optional: If you have more than one calendar and want to change which one you're adding the event to, go to the top and tap the
>   calendar name.
> - Tap Save.

References

1. [Google Calendar help: Change calendar time zone without changing event times](https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpEwvS8mv9UzUg/?hl=en)
2. [Google Calendar help: Create an event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143?visit_id=1-636299218986406127-1811739097&rd=1#time_zone)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try turning "Automatic time zone" off?

- Go into the Settings app,
- Scroll down and select "Date & time",
- Click the toggle named "Automatic time zone" until it turns grey.

Now, make sure you've selected the desired time zone under the "Select time zone" option.